# Adding header authorisation with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have made a simple api, I know that it is working as I have tested it with PostMan. I would like to consume this in a standalone Java application. One solution I have found is to use Jersey. For my purposes I just need to do a get request. Here is what I have so far but I am just getting 404 Bad request:

```
package apitest;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class Apitest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget target=client.target("http://188.166.152.46/task_manager/v1/tasks");

    System.out.println(target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));

    }

}
```

This shouldn't work as I also need to add authorisation in the header. I would expect it to return "API key missing" though.

Can you see what I have done wrong? The test api is up and running. Also, how would I add the authorisation in the header? If not Jersey, do you know of anything else that would be suitable and easy to use with documentation that even an idiot could follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working... The method [`SyncInvoker::get(java.lang.Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#get-java.lang.Class-) throws an exception in this case. You can catch the exception and print the response:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target=client.target("http://188.166.152.46/task_manager/v1/tasks");
try{
    target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
} catch (WebApplicationException ex) {
    Response response = ex.getResponse();
    System.out.println(response.getStatusInfo() + "(" + response.getStatus()  + ")");
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
}
```

If you dislike to catch the exception, you can use [`SyncInvoker::get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#get--), which returns the [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) in the case of an unsuccessful request (HTTP-status != 2xx) too:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target=client.target("http://188.166.152.46/task_manager/v1/tasks");
Response response =target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
System.out.println(response.getStatusInfo() + "(" + response.getStatus()  + ")");
System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

To add headers use the [Invocation.Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html):

```java
Invocation.Builder builder = client
        .target("http://188.166.152.46/task_manager/v1/tasks")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer apikey");
Response response = builder.get();
```

This stuff is documented in chapter [5.3.5. Invoking a HTTP request](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/2.27/client.html#d0e4716).

Comment: I do not know what your server wants :) Maybe he do not want an authorization header? maybe something like this: `.header("X-API-KEY", "1")`, but you have to check the documentation of your server...

Comment: Managed to get it working thanks :) How would you do the try and expect for Invocation.Builder?

Comment: take this method: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.Builder.html#get(java.lang.Class) The Builder implements SyncInvoker ... so the same like shown in the first code snippelt